# Adding Background color to KineticJS Text object

Tags: html5-canvas, kineticjs

Any Idea how can we add bg color to a Text object added to stage using KineticJS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this :
http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-text-tutorial/

You probably have to **add a background object**(A rectangle preferably) and use the ***fill*** property on that..and then put the text object **over that**.

The entire tutorial is within that link.

Check it out.

Comment: I was also thinking of the same solution. Is there any property available for text object for Bg color without using rect?

Comment: i dont think you can.... i think this is the only way.
And if this helped you out,do check the answer :)

Comment: +1  Yes, a rect+text is the way to give background to text.  In fact, the Kinetic.Label plugin does it like that:  https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/blob/master/src/plugins/Label.js  If you need to reposition the rect+text, you can put it in a Kinetic.Group and just reposition the group.

Comment: Yay markE approved my answer... there's no stopping me today :D